# Compact hyperkahler manifold as algebraic variety in weighted projective space?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, projective-varieties

Many examples of Calabi-Yau manifolds are constructed as algebraic varieties in weighted projective space, or more generally as complete intersection Calabi-Yau (CICY) manifolds.  Are there such realizations of compact hyperkahler manifolds besides K3?  If no, is there a fundamental obstruction?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If $X$ is a hypersurface and $\dim(X) > 2$ then by Lefschetz hyperplane theorem $H^{2,0}(X) = 0$, hence $X$ can't by hyperkahler.

Comment: Thank you. What about the case when $X$ is a higher co-dimension variety in a product of weighted projective spaces?

Comment: If $X$ (of dimension >2) is a complete intersection in any variety $Y$ with $H^{2,0}(Y)=0$ (such as product of projective spaces, weighted or not), then - again by Lefschetz - $X$ cannot be hyperkaehler.